# Baseball travel, performance data, and statistics

Tags: r, time-series, dataset

If I was interested in using travel to predict wins, or even individual performance, what would be the most appropriate way to do so? Let's say you have 9 players on one baseball team and you have their stats (I'm thinking common stats you would see in fantasy baseball: rbi, hits, runs, BA). I have this information for each game for each player. I also have information about the game. Variables such as:

a. # of road trips in a season

b. away game (0=away/1=home)

c. single road series (1=yes, 0=no)

d. time zones from home (1=series is 2+ time zones from home)

e. time zones from last game (1=current game is two or more time zones from last game)

So I want to tell a story about traveling and performance, but I'm not sure how to best do that. Obviously these variables are unique to each game. So each player has a BA for each game, and the travel variables could change for each game (or could stay the same - e.g., if three games in a series are played in same time zone, time zones from last game would be zero for the 2nd and 3rd game).

How would you model such data?

Comment: Have you tried reading books and articles about sabermetrics? That would probably be the place to start. The statistics of sports is a big topic, even when you narrow it down to one major sport.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I haven't checked that out but have heard of the term. I only ask this question here because we have a very specific question about travel and individual performance that I'm hoping to figure out how to model. It's not so much that I have an interest in sports stats, but hope to answer a very specific question with sports stats.

Comment: I would recommend hiring somebody else to do it, then—otherwise, you'll have to spend a lot of time reading and practicing how to model baseball in order to actually apply those skills once. Rome was not built in a day.